# Proxy with urllib2

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I open urls with:

`site = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')`

And what I want to do is connect the same way with a proxy
I got somewhere telling me:

`site = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com', proxies={'http':'127.0.0.1'})`

but that didn't work either.

I know urllib2 has something like a proxy handler, but I can't recall that function.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Hi, @ZelluX, I only want the proxies setting enabled on some function, does that mean I have to install and uninstall the opener for every invocation of the function?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic Maybe you can write a decorator to simplify the install/uninstall process?

Comment: Seems there's no `uninstall` method in `urllib2`, but we can make one-time proxy settings; instead of `installing` the opener, we create a `request` object, and use a opener to `open` it.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: I think the traditional approach is to configure an environment variable like `HTTP_PROXY` and then check in your code if it is defined using `os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]`.

Comment: don't forget the port number eg 3128    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:3128'})

Comment: @satoru, you can mimic uninstall through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276689/how-do-i-unit-test-a-module-that-relies-on-urllib2#comment42948730_2276884)

Comment: how does this know what port to use??

Comment: For everybody using the solution above and wondering why the created `ProxyHandler` isn't used: I needed to use this solution for getting things working because I created an additional `context` for SSL verification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24766345/520162

Answer (score 20):

You have to install a ProxyHandler

```
urllib2.install_opener(
    urllib2.build_opener(
        urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
    )
)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: I get

  File "D:/Desktop/Desktop/mygoogl", line 64,
    site = url.urlopen('google.com)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
AttributeError: ProxyHandler instance has no attribute 'open'

Comment: I missed a call to urllib2.build_opener()

Answer (score 13):

You can set proxies using environment variables.

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

`urllib2` will add proxy handlers automatically this way. You need to set proxies for different protocols separately otherwise they will fail (in terms of not going through proxy), see below.

For example:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
# next line will fail (will not go through the proxy) (https)
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

Instead

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': '127.0.0.1',
    'https': '127.0.0.1'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# this way both http and https requests go through the proxy
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have used e.g. os.environ['http_proxy'] in your lower two sets of examples?

Answer (score 8):

To use the default system proxies (e.g. from the http_support environment variable), the following works for the current request (without installing it into urllib2 globally):

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/'
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
in_ = opener.open(url)
in_.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

In Addition to the accepted answer:
My scipt gave me an error

```
File "c:\Python23\lib\urllib2.py", line 580, in proxy_open
    if '@' in host:
TypeError: iterable argument required
```

Solution was to add http:// in front of the proxy string:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://proxy.xy.z:8080'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

One can also use requests if we would like to access a web page using proxies. Python 3 code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> proxy = '169.50.87.252:80'
>>> requests.get(url, proxies={"http":proxy})
<Response [200]>
```

More than one proxies can also be added.

```
>>> proxy1 = '169.50.87.252:80'
>>> proxy2 = '89.34.97.132:8080'
>>> requests.get(url, proxies={"http":proxy1,"http":proxy2})
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Hi @WaqarDetho How will one know what proxy addresses to use? Is it just some random ip addresses?

Comment: Hi @AmanSingh I did this long time ago. But as far as I remember I find these proxy addresses from the internet. I manually injected them in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition set the proxy for the command line session
Open a command line where you might want to run your script

```
netsh winhttp set proxy YourProxySERVER:yourProxyPORT
```

run your script in that terminal.