# How can I open a website with urllib via proxy in Python?

Tags: python, proxy

I have this program that check a website, and I want to know how can I check it via proxy in Python...

this is the code, just for example

```
while True:
    try:
        h = urllib.urlopen(website)
        break
    except:
        print '['+time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')+'] '+'ERROR. Trying again in a few seconds...'
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: urllib2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2

Answer (score 56, accepted):

By default, `urlopen` uses the environment variable `http_proxy` to determine which HTTP proxy to use:

```
$ export http_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:1234'
$ python myscript.py  # Using http://myproxy.example.com:1234 as a proxy
```

If you instead want to specify a proxy inside your application, you can give a `proxies` argument to `urlopen`:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://myproxy.example.com:1234'}
print("Using HTTP proxy %s" % proxies['http'])
urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxies)
```

**Edit:** If I understand your comments correctly, you want to try several proxies and print each proxy as you try it.  How about something like this?

```
candidate_proxies = ['http://proxy1.example.com:1234',
                     'http://proxy2.example.com:1234',
                     'http://proxy3.example.com:1234']
for proxy in candidate_proxies:
    print("Trying HTTP proxy %s" % proxy)
    try:
        result = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com", proxies={'http': proxy})
        print("Got URL using proxy %s" % proxy)
        break
    except:
        print("Trying next proxy in 5 seconds")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: using your example, how can I print what proxy it is using in the time the urlopen occur?

Comment: @Shady: Just throw in a `print` statement that prints the value of `proxies['http']`.  Take a look at my updated example to see how it could be done.

Comment: ok thanks, but if I want more proxies, like, tons of it, for example 10 proxies, opening one before the next one

Comment: @Shady: You mean that you want to try a new proxy for each call until you find one that works?  Change the `proxies` argument for each call to `urlopen`, passing in a new proxy for each call.

Comment: actually, I want to check the website with some proxies, like 10, and then repeat the proccess with this proxies, but the question here is HOW can I print what proxy the urlopen is using at the time of the check

Comment: @Shady: I've added another example that uses several proxies.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you... now I just need some proxy list very good =p

Comment: Wieslander, I'm getting error for every proxy I use, what could be?

Comment: @Shady: That's impossible to tell without more details.  I would start by verifying that the proxies actually work by trying them out in a web browser first. If they **don't** work in the browser either, then the problem is probably with the proxies or in the network.  If they **do** work in the browser, you'll probably have to double check that you're actually passing the proxy settings correctly to `urlopen`.

Comment: Wieslander, I've just tested the proxy and it worked on firefox, I've got it from here (http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm).. could you give some look on my script to see what is happening ? I will appreciate =) (http://pastebin.com/TgZw7xvV)

Comment: My `response = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies = proxies}` doesnt work. Doesnt give any output. Any idea?

Comment: `urllib.urlopen` in Python 3 doen't have parameter `proxies`. It out of dated: 

> Proxy handling, which was done by passing a dictionary parameter to urllib.urlopen, can be obtained by using ProxyHandler objects.

Comment: And you can use the first environment variable method. It's the simplest.

Answer (score 59):

Python 3 is slightly different here. It will try to auto detect proxy settings but if you need specific or manual proxy settings, think about this kind of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : 'http://user:pass@server:port', 
                                             'https': 'https://...'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    # ... implement things such as 'html = response.read()'
```

Refer also to [the relevant section in the Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/urllib2.html#proxies)

Answer (score 6):

Here example code guide how to use urllib to connect via proxy:

```
authinfo = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http" : "http://ahad-haam:3128"})

# build a new opener that adds authentication and caching FTP handlers
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support, authinfo,
                                     urllib.request.CacheFTPHandler)

# install it
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
"""
```

Comment: Can you explain what is authinfo and give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For http and https use:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://proxy-source-ip:proxy-port',
           'https':'https://proxy-source-ip:proxy-port'}
```

more proxies can be added similarly

```
proxies = {'http':'http://proxy1-source-ip:proxy-port',
           'http':'http://proxy2-source-ip:proxy-port'
           ...
          }
```

usage

```
filehandle = urllib.urlopen( external_url , proxies=proxies)
```

Don't use any proxies (in case of links within network)

```
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(external_url, proxies={})
```

Use proxies authentication via username and password

```
proxies = {'http':'http://username:password@proxy-source-ip:proxy-port',
           'https':'https://username:password@proxy-source-ip:proxy-port'}
```

> Note: avoid using special characters such as `:,@` in username and passwords