# How to accessing wikipedia API through a PROXY in Python

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, wikipedia-api

I'm using wikitools to acces the wikipedia API, but I'm behind a proxy and I have no idea how to access the website through the proxy when the accessing process is on the form:

```
site = wiki.Wiki("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php")
req = api.APIRequest(site, params)
```

where params is the parameters I want extracted.

Comment: See [How can I open a website with urllib via proxy in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the environment varable 
     `http_proxy` and added the proxy adress