# Spoofing IP address when web scraping (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, tcp

I have made a web scraper in `python` to give me information on when free bet offers from various bookie websites have changed or new ones have been added.

However, the bookies tend to record information relating to `IP` traffic and `MAC` addresses in order to flag up matched betters.

How can I spoof my `IP` address when using the `Request()` method in the `urllib.request` module?

My code is below:

```
req = Request('https://www.888sport.com/online-sports-betting-promotions/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
site = urlopen(req).read()
content = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: you can make use of proxy chains, to achieve this!

Comment: this site filters by country, you need a valid proxy for do it

Comment: req = Request
    req.set_proxy(r, "HTTP").

This is throwing up an error saying set_proxy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'type'.

       r is a 127.x.x.x IP address (I'm using it for the purpose of testing)

Comment: Literally the first link in google for "Python proxy urllib" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python

Comment: I've had really, really good results with Crawera!

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same problem a while ago. Here is my code snippet, which I am using, in order to scrape anonymously.

First install the required packages: `pip3 install fake-useragent ipython`

Here is the source-code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.core.display import clear_output

# Here I provide some proxies for not getting caught while scraping
ua = UserAgent() # From here we generate a random user agent
proxies = [] # Will contain proxies [ip, port]

# Main function
def main():
  # Retrieve latest proxies
  proxies_req = Request('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
  proxies_req.add_header('User-Agent', ua.random)
  proxies_doc = urlopen(proxies_req).read().decode('utf8')

  soup = BeautifulSoup(proxies_doc, 'html.parser')
  proxies_table = soup.find(id='proxylisttable')

  # Save proxies in the array
  for row in proxies_table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
    proxies.append({
      'ip':   row.find_all('td')[0].string,
      'port': row.find_all('td')[1].string
    })

  # Choose a random proxy
  proxy_index = random_proxy()
  proxy = proxies[proxy_index]

  for n in range(1, 20):
    req = Request('http://icanhazip.com')
    req.set_proxy(proxy['ip'] + ':' + proxy['port'], 'http')

    # Every 10 requests, generate a new proxy
    if n % 10 == 0:
      proxy_index = random_proxy()
      proxy = proxies[proxy_index]

    # Make the call
    try:
      my_ip = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
      print('#' + str(n) + ': ' + my_ip)
      clear_output(wait = True)
    except: # If error, delete this proxy and find another one
      del proxies[proxy_index]
      print('Proxy ' + proxy['ip'] + ':' + proxy['port'] + ' deleted.')
      proxy_index = random_proxy()
      proxy = proxies[proxy_index]

# Retrieve a random index proxy (we need the index to delete it if not working)
def random_proxy():
  return random.randint(0, len(proxies) - 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

That will create some proxies which are working. And the this part:

```
user_agent_list = (
   #Chrome
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
    #Firefox
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)'
)
```

Which will create different "headers", pretending to be a browser.
Last but not least just enter those into you request().

```
 # Make a get request
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    headers= {'User-Agent': user_agent, "Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    response = get("your url", headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
```

Hope that works with you problem.

Otherwise look here: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/

Cheers

Comment: Hey @Yannik Suhre thanks for this. Can you clarify how user_agent_list gets generated in the first code block? I see it (user_agent_list) in the second code block (user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)) but don't quite get how it's created from BeautifulSoup, urllib.request, fake_useragent & all other other imports in the first code block...

Comment: @JC23 the `user_agent_list` (which is a list although I wrongly wrote it as tuple above) is just the block copy+paste'd. So if you want to use this, you have to copy this list too. Hence this list does not depend on BS, request or any other package, bascially it is just a `list` of strings. Does this clarify it for you? Otherwise please ask again.

Comment: Hey @Yannik Suhre thanks for the quick reply. I guess I was just dizzy or misread your answer.

Comment: @YannikSuhre I explained you also need to install both `fake-useragent` and `ipython` packages.

Answer (score 5):

In order to overcome IP rate ban and hide your real IP you need to use proxies. There are a lot of different services that provide proxies. Consider using them as managing proxies by yourself is a real headache and cost would be much higher. I suggest https://botproxy.net among others. They provide rotating proxies though a single endpoint. Here is how you can make requests using this service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.ProxyHandler(
        {'http': 'http://user-key:key-password@x.botproxy.net:8080',
         'https': 'http://user-key:key-password@x.botproxy.net:8080'}))
print(opener.open('https://httpbin.org/ip').read())
```

or using requests library

```
import requests

res = requests.get(
    'http://httpbin.org/ip',
    proxies={
        'http': 'http://user-key:key-password@x.botproxy.net:8080',
        'https': 'http://user-key:key-password@x.botproxy.net:8080'
        },
    headers={
        'X-BOTPROXY-COUNTRY': 'US'
        })
print(res.text)
```

They also have proxies in different countries.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to browse anonymously. You can use some of free proxy sites in order to get proxies and update proxy = {}.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ''
proxy = {"http":"http://","https":"http://"}
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},proxies=proxy)
content = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
```