# Why can't I establish a connection to the Uber API?

Tags: python, api, proxy, uber-api

I ran the code as per the documentation

```
from uber_rides.session import Session
from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient

session = Session(server_token=<TOKEN>)
client = UberRidesClient(session)
response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)
```

I am behind a proxy server though. And this following connection error was raised.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 141, in _new_conn
>       (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
>   line 83, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
>   line 73, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 600, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 345, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 844, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 284, in connect
>       conn = self._new_conn()   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py",
>   line 150, in _new_conn
>       self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
>   : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 423, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 649, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
>   line 376, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.uber.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /v1.2/products?latitude=37.77&longitude=-122.41
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uber_rides/client.py",
>   line 124, in get_products
>       return self._api_call('GET', 'v1.2/products', args=args)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uber_rides/client.py",
>   line 104, in _api_call
>       return request.execute()   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uber_rides/request.py",
>   line 152, in execute
>       return self._send(prepared_request)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uber_rides/request.py",
>   line 136, in _send
>       response = session.send(prepared_request)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 609, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/djokester/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 487, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.uber.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /v1.2/products?latitude=37.77&longitude=-122.41
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely help add support for a proxy to the Uber python sdk: [How can I open a website with urllib via proxy in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python)

Comment: I think that even though the first solution can help me, it wouldn't suit my need. If I am trying to build an application or a package that is a really very messy solution.

Comment: I think this is the only way to configure proxy support for urllib. The rides python sdk uses requests which uses urllib which is the core of the issue. We can add proxy support to the backlog.