# Web Scraping in python3

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to collect some data from a website , but it gives me not available in your country webpage. I tried using a proxy server from the same country but it didn't help. 
Here is my code

```
import urllib.request 
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http':'149.56.44.146:9201'}) 
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support) 
urllib.request.install_opener(opener) 
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.seamless.com') as response:
  print(response​.read())
```

I don't know what's wrong here. Can someone help pls.

Comment: I tested your program and what you get isn't an "error" at all, it's just a page that says that (so you might want to edit that word). Having said that, I get the same message. Perhaps the proxy is also in a country that doesn't receive service? have you tried multiple proxies from different countries?

Comment: I tried using a vpn and found out that it works in Usa and then i used a proxy server from usa and yeah i have tried a lot of usa proxies all leading to the same html page.

Comment: Edited thank you sir.

Comment: @Ofer Sadan , sir my problem is how to get the job done using proxy itself.

Comment: have a look at the answers for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python because they use a different method to proxy than the one you use, check if that works

Comment: Sir that's because its python3 that i am using and they use python2.7.
The answer just below the one uses the same technique and the major issue is even though i use a proxy the website still doesn't give me complete access

Comment: Or just look up your IP when using the proxy in order to check if the proxy is working at all.

Comment: One advice: Use requests instead of Urllib. 
Requests more soft, more clever.
Use headers (some sites recognize your country with headers (language etc)).

Comment: I tried and the ip is same in both cases. But I don't understand why the proxy is not connecting

Answer (score 0):

you can use a module such as splash which has a proxy built-in, it can help you get past your country error problem

https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash