# Urlopen() proxies keyword doesn't exist?

Tags: python, urlopen

When I use the code below, it returns the following error:

```py
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.urlopen(input(), proxies={
    "http": "37.26.86.206",
    "https": "37.26.86.206"
}))
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path]", line 2, in <module>
    print(urllib.request.urlopen(input(), proxies={
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
```

However, this was used in multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168171/how-can-i-open-a-website-with-urllib-via-proxy-in-python).
Is this method just outdated, or is there a flaw in my code?
Note: All code is included here.

Comment: Check this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/36881923/3215376

Comment: tchar I tried that and it returns a TypeError:
print(urllib.request(input()))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was removed in Python 3.5
Thank you everyone for your help!