# connecting to a website using proxies and urllib?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

If the proxy is `200.217.241.76` and the port is `80` how can i connect to `google.com` and read the html code using that proxy?

My problem is to establish the connection i know how to read the html file when i get it, 
i want to automate a script that keep on reading different html files and save the data.

what i have now :

```
import urllib
html = urllib.openurl("http://google.com").read()
# do stuff with html
```

an example would be great !

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2

Answer (score 0):

urllib honors the system proxy settings:

> The urlopen() function works transparently with proxies which do not
>   require authentication. In a Unix or Windows environment, set the
>   http_proxy, or ftp_proxy environment variables to a URL that
>   identifies the proxy server before starting the Python interpreter.
>   For example (the '%' is the command prompt):

```
> % http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128" 
> % export http_proxy 
> % python ...
```

[enter link description here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)