# How to send a packet via proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, packet

How would I go about doing this in python? I need to establish a stronger connection than I may have to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using urllib2 (which is the easiest way to fetch resources from a http server), you need to set the `http_proxy` environment variable.

If your proxy is unauthenticated it will be something like:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:port/
```

If your proxy is authenicating, it will be:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/
```

If you want to do this programattically, you can manually do this using a [proxy handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2/1450154#1450154).

Comment: And how would you link multiple proxies?

Comment: In what way are you trying to "link" proxies? Do you need to do some kind of forwarding (ala squid? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29)