# Fetching URL with proxy in between

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to obtain any site. Normally while browsing there is a script that is configured in browser i.e there is a link to the location of that script given in

```
tools->internet options->connections->lan settings
```

How do I incorporate that, without that script the pages arent fetched.

I also tried this

[Proxy With urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2)

But it talks about proxy authentication 407 error.

How to go forward with,could anyone please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `http_proxy` variable, syntax of which is:

`HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.example.com:port/`

In Windows, right click on My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables

You will see user variables and system variables. System variables are universal (will work for any logged in user), and to change them you need administrator level access. User variables work for you account and you can modify them without administrator access.

Click New on whichever one you prefer and set the environment variables.