# Python: Disable http_proxy in urllib2

Tags: python, proxy, environment-variables, urllib2

I am using a proxy set as an environment variable (export http_proxy=example.com).  For one call using urllib2 I need to temporarily disable this, ie. unset the http_proxy.  I have tried various methods suggested in the documentation and interwebs, but so far have been unable to unset the proxy.  So far I have tried:

```
# doesn't work
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
req.set_proxy(None,None)
urllib2.urlopen(req)

# also doesn't work
urllib.getproxies = lambda x = None: {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The urllib2 documentation [suggests](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler) the following should work. Is it one of the approaches you have tried?

```
import urllib2

proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
page = opener.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put this before the code where you want to disable system proxies.

```
import urllib2
urllib2.getproxies = lambda: {}
```

Sometimes it's better than creating empty `ProxyHandler` because it works for external libraries, even if they create [their own `urllib2` openers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089694/python-how-to-handle-https-request-with-urllib2-ssl-though-a-http-proxy).

Also the possible way is temporary disable proxy with `contextmanager` decorator, but I can't bet on that it will work with multi threads:

```
import selenium
import urllib2
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def no_proxies():
    orig_getproxies = urllib2.getproxies
    urllib2.getproxies = lambda: {}
    yield
    urllib2.getproxies = orig_getproxies

with no_proxies():
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Ie()
    driver.get("http://google.com")
```

In this example we prevent `python-selenium` to use system proxy setting which entails errors like these:

[IE and Chrome not working with Selenium2 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625047/ie-and-chrome-not-working-with-selenium2-python)

[Unable to run IEDriverServer.exe with proxy set up in IE internet option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914561/unable-to-run-iedriverserver-exe-with-proxy-set-up-in-ie-internet-option)

Comment: `urllib2.getproxies = lambda: {}` This worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work in my case, and didn't digg so much on that, just monkeypatched the socks module.

Comment: Downvote for stating that monkey-patching (global state (sic!)) is better than designated API.

Comment: Piotr, unfortunately the designed API doesn't works in some cases if you meant ProxyHandler solution

Comment: Vyacheslav, I would like to know in what case it does not work?

Comment: Piotr, Sure. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089694/python-how-to-handle-https-request-with-urllib2-ssl-though-a-http-proxy). Wow! You've already answered on this. :) Anyway, I faced with such problem long time ago when I used third-party library, maybe it was related to this problem about "not global" opener.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using proxy for a known set of sites, you can use the `no_proxy` environment variable like this:

```
$ export no_proxy="google.com,stackoverflow.com,mysite.org:8080"
```

(comma-separated list of hostname suffixes, port can be specified as well)

This should work with both `urllib` and `urllib2`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is monkeypatching the socks library like this:

```
import socks, socket, urllib2
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(None, None) # this does ["0.0.0.0"], [0]
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection
print urllib2.urlopen("http://httpbin.org/ip").read()
```

So, seems that if you set it as `0.0.0.0` at port `0` at least, should avoid using it because the `inet_aton()` library wouldn't accept `0.0.0.0` as valid IP.

Obviously I've not really checked why what... but, indeed works.
The most easy way to check is set first a proxy, fetch a url with any library and try again without set a proxy. You'll get catched by last setted proxy :) unless you "unset" it for the following connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the proxy by installing an emtpy ProxyHandler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request, ProxyHandler, build_opener, install_opener, urlretrieve

def unset_http_https_proxy():
    proxy_support = ProxyHandler()
    opener = build_opener(proxy_support)
    install_opener(opener)
```