# IE and Chrome not working with Selenium2 Python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to open up Google Chrome or Internet Explorer through Selenium 2's Python library. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit.

I have completed the following steps:

- Installed python - 2.7.5
- Installed selenium 2.33
- Included C:\Python27 & C:\Python27\Scripts in the Environment Variable - Path
- Downloaded the 32 bit (I am running 64 bit but I could not find the 32 bit version) windows Chrome Driver that supports v27-30 (I am on 28) and placed it into C:\Python27\Scripts
- Downloaded the 64 bit IE driver that supports up to IE9 (I downgraded IE10 to IE9). I placed the driver into C:\Python27\Scripts

Whenever I type:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie()
```

OR

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

into the Python shell, no browser pops up, the shell just freezes for a couple of minutes and then outputs an error message.

IE Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to the IEDriver'
```

Chrome Error message:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

It works perfectly fine with firefox. The funny thing is, is that the process (IEDriver and ChromeDriver) starts per the TaskManager, but the window never shows up.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried placing it into its own folder and updating the PATH, but that still did not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python-selenium `webdriver.Ie` is just a shortcut for executing **IEDriver.exe** and connecting to it through `webdriver.Remote`. For example, you could start **IEDriver.exe** from command line:

```
> IEDriverServer.exe
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.39.0.0
Listening on port 5555
```

and replace `webdriver.Ie()` with the following code:

```
webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:5555',
                 desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER)`
```

You will get the same result.

Specifically in your case is most likely that you have some system proxy settings that force it connect to *127.0.0.1* through proxy server. Probably when you disable it as described in answer [Python: Disable http_proxy in urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358781/python-disable-http-proxy-in-urllib2/24766345#24766345), you can solve the problem:

```
import selenium
import urllib2
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def no_proxies():
    orig_getproxies = urllib2.getproxies
    urllib2.getproxies = lambda: {}
    yield
    urllib2.getproxies = orig_getproxies

with no_proxies():
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Ie()
    driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Comment: Yes, check your enviroment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to solve this problem with the path I've downloaded it to, but have been able to workaround it by defining the path to the driver, like so:

```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\path\to\chromedriver')
```

or

```
   driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\path\to\iedriver')
```

Comment: To make things even more confusing, This works with Chrome only for me. Ie still gives me an error message... I am confused