# httplib and HTTPs proxies

Tags: python, https, proxy, httplib

Is there a way to tunnel HTTPs requests made with python's `httplib` through Fiddler's proxy, without turning Fiddler into a reverse proxy?

I tried using this example (from [here](https://gist.github.com/2149495)):

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection('localhost',8118)
c.set_tunnel('twitter.com',443)
c.request('GET','/')
r1 = c.getresponse()
print r1.status,r1.reason
data1 = r1.read()
print len(data1)
```

but it returns:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><TITLE>Fiddler Echo Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY STYLE="font-family: arial,sans-serif;"><H1>Fiddler Echo Service</H1><BR /><PRE>GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: identity

</PRE><BR><HR><UL><LI>To configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy instead of seeing this page, see <A HREF='http://fiddler2.com/r/?REVERSEPROXY'>Reverse Proxy Setup</A><LI>You can download the <a href="FiddlerRoot.cer">FiddlerRoot certificate</A></UL></BODY></HTML>
```

EDIT:
This code works. The problem was related to proxy settings in Internet Explorer. DO NOT set a proxy in these settings, otherwise code above won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried with urllib2 ([Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2)) through a Burp proxy and it worked:

```
import urllib2
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': '127.0.0.1:8081'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com').read()
```

Your code seems to work just fine with Burp Suite proxy.

Comment: Does your second example work with Burp? It does not work with Fiddler.

Comment: Well, no, it unfortunately doesn't. I am not able to tunnel connections or am doing something wrong. Are you forced to use httplib?

Comment: Either way, I'll try to investigate it furthermore. Once you'll get it first, don't forget to post your solution here.

Comment: Yes, it seems I'm stuck with httplib, because it allows more fine-grained time measurements.

Comment: Actually, I was able to run your code through Burp proxy, and it seems you set addresses correctly. I'll edit my answer not to confuse other users. What version of Fiddler proxy do you have problems with?

Comment: And yes, default installation of Fiddler proxy v2 I managed to tunnel connection back to Twitter. What versions of Python and Fiddler proxy do you have?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Fiddler v2.4.0.6 and python 2.7.

Comment: Check your proxy configuration then. I ran it on defaults and had no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Indeed, I think this had something to do with proxy settings in internet explorer. Removing proxy from these settings fixed the problem. Thanks for investigating this :)