# Python urllib urlretrieve behind proxy

Tags: python, urllib2

I looked into the documentation of urllib but all I could find on proxies was related to urlopen. However, I want to download a PDF from a given URL and store it locally but using a certain proxy server. My approach so far which did not work:

```
import urllib2

proxies = {'http': 'http://123.96.220.2:81'}
opener = urllib2.FancyURLopener(proxies)
download = opener.urlretrieve(URL, file_name)
```

The error is `AttributeError: FancyURLopener instance has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beleive you can do something like this:

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '123.96.220.2:81'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

with open('filename','wb') as f:
    f.write(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
    f.close()
```

since `urllib2` doesnt have `urlretrieve`
you can just use `urlopen` to get the same effect

you must have got the docs confused becuase `urllib2` also doesnt have `FancyURLopener` thats why youre getting the error

`urllib2` is much better when handling proxies and such

for more info look here [Urllib2 Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: I just checked `urllib2.urlopen(URL, filename)`. This does not work as it does not download and store the PDF given the filename.

Comment: all the gz file that I downloaded using this are corrupted, they are not when I use google chrome

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea you're just missing a few [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2).

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```