# How can I use urllib.request.urlretrieve with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to get images dowloaded from image-net.org so that I can create a haar cascade classifier. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_6fPS5tDNU&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdttJXlLtAJxJetJcqmqlQq&index=18 but I am using python 2.7 instead of python 3. So in the tutorial he has the line:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, pathToImage)
```

Instead of `import urllib.request` I did this `import urllib2` So I tried this but it isn't vaild

```
urllib2.urlretrieve(i, "Negatives/"+str(num)+".jpg")
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: "but it wasn't valid" isn't particularly descriptive, what exactly went wrong?

Comment: It prints this error 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Comment: [It is in the `urllib` module in python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

Comment: That said, why are you following a tutorial for py3 but using py2, why not just get python 3?

Comment: I have python 2 installed on my raspberrypi becuase it was hard to find a tutorial for installing opencv with python 3, So I test out the code on my mac  and then I can just transfer the file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to import urllib without '2'

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(i, "Negatives/"+str(num)+".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that on different build systems, I'd have different version of Python available, totally out of my control.

So I adjusted my script to get `urlretrieve` this way:

```
import sys
print("Python: " + sys.version)
sys.stdout.flush()

import os, re, difflib

# because somewhere along the line they  may have deprecated `urlretrieve`
#   mentioned in docs for python [3.5.5, 3.6.6, 3.7.0, 3.8.0a0] that:
#       `[urlretrieve] might become deprecated at some point in the future.`
def UrlRetrieve(url, fname=None):
  if sys.version_info[0] <= 2:
    import urllib
    return urllib.urlretrieve(url, fname)
  elif sys.version_info[0] <= 3:
    import urllib.request
    return urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fname)
  else:
    import shutil
    import tempfile
    import urllib.request
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
      if fname is None:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
          shutil.copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)
          return (tmp_file.name, response.info())
      else:
        with io.open(fname) as the_file:
          shutil.copyfileobj(response, the_file)
          return (fname, response.info())
```

Then, use it this way:

```
url = "http://...whatever.../bootstrap.zip"
pair = UrlRetrieve(url)
```

And then, because what I was importing was definitely python 2, I needed to do this in the 3 world:

```
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
  import zipfile
  zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(pair[0], 'r')
  zip_ref.extractall(pair[0] + ".d")
  zip_ref.close()
  import os
  os.system("2to3 -w " + pair[0] + ".d")
  sys.path.append(pair[0] + ".d")
else:
  sys.path.append(pair[0])
from bootstrap_common import *
```

I now keep these snippets handle for future scripts where I need to use `urlretrieve` on both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

on this [Python urllib urlretrieve behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449904/python-urllib-urlretrieve-behind-proxy)

```
import urllib2

download = opener.urlretrieve(URL, "Negatives/"+str(num)+".jpg")
```

the code can be transformed to

```
import urllib2

with open("Negatives/"+str(num)+".jpg",'wb') as f:
    f.write(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
```

Comment: Won't the `with` handle the `f.close()` for you?