# Truely Bypass Stubborn Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, network-programming

How do I bypass very stubborn proxy in a workplace through python. By bypass, I mean I would be able to fill in the username and password and it would allow me access from my python scripts.

I noticed that it's only some selects apps like Web browsers that can pass through and a download-er that I use. My anti-virus can't go through.

The problem is that I use Python on this machine and would love to continue working with things like urllib2.

Comment: Yes, python library `proxy` conveniently enough has a function `bypass_stubborn`... Seriously though, what do you mean by 'bypass'? What does your script need to do?

Comment: I need to simply access the network from my script. As simple as: urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a Microsoft ISA server thing. You would have to get across to the network administrator to be able to have a measure of success in what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is it really necessary to bypass the proxy? After all, they are more and more common, so if you are *forced* to go around it then ask yourself why the policies it enforces are in place. Please don't fall foul of any conditions of use by undertaking programming self-education.

Secondly, even if this work is approved, wouldn't it be better to learn to work through the proxy? The library is capable of doing it, and it isn't that difficult: see [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2) for one sample of how much work it takes.

Of course, if you are hoping to use Python to bypass corporate policy then you are on your own. You will most likely find the firewall only lets the proxy make outgoing web connections (and similar) if you try to communicate directly. It's the proxy's job to be stubborn. Think carefully about the reasons it's there before going too far.

Comment: I just need to make my script read data from the internet. And the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2 doesn't work for me, I've tried it out in the past.