# Router blocking response from external networks

Tags: security, networking

I'm working on a company network right now, and I've come across a problem where my scripts cannot connect to external networks. I'm just wondering if anyone knows common practices in network security that may cause this?

Ex. I can visit www.example.com on firefox, but my python script will get a timeout error if it tries to connect.

These scripts work perfectly fine on another network or if I change the URL to something on the local network.

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print(f.read(300))
```

**ANSWER**: the browser uses the network's proxy. Scripts also have to use that proxy to run

```
import urllib.request

proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print(req.read())
```

Comment: Check the proxy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that your browser is configured to use a proxy. If that is true, then you will need to augment your python script with ProxyHandler (see [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2))

Comment: Well that was easy, but how does 127.0.0.1 get the proxy? I thought 127 addresses just return the request to the computer

Comment: @Alter The argument to ProxyHandler() should be a dictionary that contains the proxy settings used in your network. 127.0.0.1 cannot be a valid proxy. Ask your network admin, or look in your browser settings to view the proxy's IP address and port number.

Comment: I'm very confused, it works perfectly with 127.0.0.1 - could it be that python knows this is an invalid proxy and gets the system proxy instead?

Comment: I lied, it does not work perfectly, I was mistaking any response for the correct response... I was getting my localhost webpage

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler If you don't pass any arguments to ProxyHandler(), it will attempt to detect your http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables. Please get details of your proxy from the admin or look in your browser settings. In firefox, go to Preferences->Advanced->Settings to view your proxy settings.