# Connect python application to internet through proxy IP?

Tags: python, sockets, ip, urllib2, proxy-server

At my workplace we access internet through a proxy server IP entered in Preferences > Network > Connection > Manual Proxy configuration. where the Proxy IP is entered, I want to learn how to do that setup in python so for my internet based application .

Comment: I am looking for answer to this question for a very long time.

Comment: Are you on windows or a linux box?

Comment: Are you trying to use a Python application to connect to the internet through the proxy, or are you trying to use Python to setup your proxy connection for another application? Those are two wildly different things.

Comment: I am trying to use a Python application to connect to the internet through the proxy.

Comment: Does this SO post help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2

Comment: @mictrez I will try this tomorrow from workplace where I am behind proxies. all though still thinking how to do auto detect otherwise if behind proxy or not!

Comment: No, I get TypeError:
`File "/system/python2.4/urllib2.py", line 580, in proxy_open
    if '@' in host:
TypeError: iterable argument required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set http_proxy environment variable or you can set this information accordly with lib used. As example, requests libs:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "http://10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

**UPDATE**

A tool that can help in corporate environments is cntlm http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ , an  NTLM / NTLM Session Response / NTLMv2 authenticating HTTP proxy.

Once configured, you only have to point to your proxy in http://localhost:3128.

Comment: it gives me <Response [407]> i.e. HTTP Error 407 Proxy authentication required , which means I have to pass my username and password as argument somewhere to do a get request !

Comment: later I added username and password like mentioend here and it worked. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies