# URLError with SPARQLWrapper at sparql.query().convert()

Tags: python, sparql, jupyter-notebook, fuseki, sparqlwrapper

I try a small python script to test my SPARQL request. However, just the next simple code doesn't work.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import rdflib
#connect to the sparql point
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:3030/sparql")
#SPARQL request
sparql.setQuery("""
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rme: <http://www.semanticweb.org/reminer/>

SELECT ?o
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
LIMIT 1
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
     print(result["o"]["value"])
```

My code freezes a long time at the conversion step then gives me an URLError.
And when I stop the script, see the next message:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2ab63307a418> in <module>()
     18 """)
     19 sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
---> 20 results = sparql.query().convert()
     21 
     22 for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in query(self)
    533             @rtype: L{QueryResult} instance
    534         """
--> 535         return QueryResult(self._query())
    536 
    537     def queryAndConvert(self):

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    513                 raise EndPointInternalError(e.read())
    514             else:
--> 515                 raise e
    516 
    517     def query(self):

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py in _query(self)
    503 
    504         try:
--> 505             response = urlopener(request)
    506             return response, self.returnFormat
    507         except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    159     else:
    160         opener = _opener
--> 161     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    162 
    163 def install_opener(opener):

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    467         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    468             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 469             response = meth(req, response)
    470 
    471         return response

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    577         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    578             response = self.parent.error(
--> 579                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    580 
    581         return response

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    505         if http_err:
    506             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 507             return self._call_chain(*args)
    508 
    509 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    439         for handler in handlers:
    440             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 441             result = func(*args)
    442             if result is not None:
    443                 return result

/Users/francocy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    585 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    586     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 587         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    588 
    589 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I've the same situation with both 2.7 and 3.4.
EDIT: I changed my connection from Wifi to intranet. My script works well with DBpedia Sparql endpoint but I've a Http error when I request on my local server. It seems to be a problem of proxy or access to my local server.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to execute some SPARQL request on your local fuseki server through a python script, you could be disturbed by some proxy problem. To resolve the problem you could use the auto-detect property of urllib.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, XML
#import urllib.request module. Don't forget for Python 3.4 the urllib has been split into several different modules.
import urllib.request

#if the arg is empty in ProxyHandler, urllib will find itself your proxy config.
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

#connect to the sparql point
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:3030/yourOwnDb/sparql")
#SPARQL request
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

    SELECT ?o ?p
    WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
    LIMIT 1
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result["o"]["value"])
```

Comment: Yes I know, but there is a delay to do it. I was waiting for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For users coming here in 2019, for errors in accessing Wikidata sparql endpoint, Wikidata enforces a strict User-Agent policy, see this archived  (thanks Pere) [Wikidata Project chat](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat/Archive/2019/07#problems_with_query_API), which says that applications sending informative headers is indicative of well-behaved non-bot scripts, also see [user-agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) of Wikimedia.

According to the [documentation](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/doc/latest/SPARQLWrapper.Wrapper.SPARQLWrapper-class.html), we can set user-agent using the `agent` instance variable. The user-agent HTTP header is described in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent). 
Finally, you can initialize the class object as,

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql", agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Wikidata chat thread has been archived to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Project_chat/Archive/2019/07#problems_with_query_API

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells you:

> Operation timed out

It seems as if when you ran the code dbpedia.org wasn't reachable from your connection.

Running your code now it immediately returns the following for me:

```
http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat
```

So in production you'd probably want to catch that `URLError` and handle it somehow.

---

### Update after question edit:

Currently `SPARQLWrapper` relies on `urllib2` to perform its requests, so in case you're behind a proxy you should be able to use `urllib2`'s `ProxyHandler` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450154/1423333):

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '192.168.x.x'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# and then:
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

Comment: I change my way to be connected to internet. I switch my connection from Wifi to intranet link. It's work now. But now, I've still the problem to access to my localhost server. I get a HTTP 403 forbidden error. I don't know what kind of things the IT service I've done on my computer.

Comment: Well, the only one who can find out is you... ask your IT what your setup is (e.g., the IP of your proxy)

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jörn Hees. I tried to use ProxyHandler with my proxy http address but the problem isn't resolved. I've the same error. See my code:

`from urllib.request import *
proxy = ProxyHandler({'http': 'www-cache.***.com:3**8'})
opener = build_opener(proxy)
install_opener(opener)

#connect to the sparql point
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:3030/db/sparql")`

Comment: Thanks for you reply Jörn Hees. I was closed. That works now.
I don't use your script but I adapt it with Python 3.4.
I used the auto-detect property of urllib.
See the code:
`proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)`