# How to handle proxies in urllib3

Tags: python, proxy, urllib3

I am having trouble finding solid examples of how to build a simple script in urllib3 which opens a url (via a proxy), then reads it and finally prints it. The proxy requires a user/pass to authenticate however it's not clear to me how you do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the library, but is it reasonably similar to [Proxy with urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1450132) ?

Comment: Not really, I have done this will the urllib2 library already. I am interested to see how this is done with urllib3.

Comment: use `requests`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module

Answer (score 16, accepted):

urllib3 has a [`ProxyManager`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#proxymanager) component which you can use. You'll need to build headers for the Basic Auth component, you can either do that manually or use the [`make_headers`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.util.request.make_headers) helper in urllib3.

All together, it would look something like this:

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers

default_headers = make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='myusername:mypassword')
http = ProxyManager("https://myproxy.com:8080/", proxy_headers=default_headers)

# Now you can use `http` as you would a normal PoolManager
r = http.request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: Is the "headers" the login for the proxy, or can it be used to log into a website as well?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 It's for the proxy. You can make separate headers for the website itself.

Comment: This only worked for me when I changed "headers=default_headers" to "proxy_headers=default_headers". 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131573/urllib3-proxymanager-is-giving-authentication-error

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct answer to this should be

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers

default_headers = make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='myusername:mypassword')
http = ProxyManager("https://myproxy.com:8080/", headers=default_headers)

# Now you can use `http` as you would a normal PoolManager
r = http.request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

(note: proxy_basic_auth, not basic_auth)

I was trying this with basic_auth in my environment without any luck. [shazow you committed this comment to git which pointed me in the right direction](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/267a865cd6d29b0ffe25b544d5d1d172941b24dc)