# How to use feedparser with proxy in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, urllib3, feedparser

I'd like to use a proxy and feedparser. This is how I'd do in urllib2:

```
import urllib2, feedparser
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy:port"})
d = feedparser.parse('http://www.shop.inonit.in/RSSFeedDetails.aspx?PID=801', handlers = [proxy])
```

How do I do it with urllib3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151615/how-to-handle-proxies-in-urllib3

Comment: feedparser doesn't work with proxymanager

Answer (score 0):

```
import feedparser
from urllib.request import ProxyHandler, build_opener
proxy_handler = ProxyHandler(proxies)
print(feedparser.parse("rss_url", handlers=[proxy_handler]))
```

Similarly, we can provide a proxy handler for feed parser.

Comment: What about verification SSL certificate? in requests I used `proxies` and `verify`, I need both here.

Comment: Not works for me, I got an error:
URLError(ConnectionResetError(10054...)
Do all the same as you. Proxies adresses took from free web sites. Any ideas?