# How to authorize proxy in urllib3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

I need to use urllib3 with proxy which requires authorization

```
http = urllib3.ProxyManager('http://host:port', headers={ 'User-Agent': UA_CHROME} )
```

I have tried to pass proxy headers with login and password like this

```
proxy_header={'login': login, 'password': pass}
```

and I used options in these answers [How to handle proxies in urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151615/how-to-handle-proxies-in-urllib3) but it did not help.
How can I authorize my proxy in urllib3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle proxies in urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151615/how-to-handle-proxies-in-urllib3)

Comment: I wrote that it did not help