# Web Scraping using BeauitifulSoup error : [Errno 10061]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to make this piece of code work : ( web scraping sample using BeautifulSoup )

```
import urllib2    
wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"
page = urllib2.urlopen(wiki)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

I get this error :-

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I guess it is to do with some firewall/security related issue, can someone help with what should be done?

Comment: I think, you need to set proxy

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2

Comment: requests is better to use

Comment: @AnishShah - The code snippet there in the example throws the same error  :     URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"
page = requests.get(wiki).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

---

If you are trying to get the table, you can use pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"
df = pd.read_html(wiki)[1]
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df.iloc[0]
df2.drop(0, inplace=True)
df2.drop('No.', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I end up with the same error :- ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000005DFF4A8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))   ---- when I tried the first snippet.

Comment: @Indi This has to do something with proxies I guess. Read this: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2875

Comment: @Indi Can you give me the versions you are using --> `os`, `python`, `BeautifulSoup`, `requests`?