# urllib2 allow redirects on a url using proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to request a url using proxy. However response is HttpError 302 Found saying redirection is not allowed.

Code:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', user_agent)]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print('Performing request')
return urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Detailed Error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found - Redirection to url 'market://details/?id=com.UCMobile.intl&referrer=utm_source%3Dhexn%40adinallBrowser%25239%26utm_content%3Dclickid%253A29lu41t4865766358092300dfe678d89%253Buc_trans_1%253AhiKpNb0003n190X0FH00CHdX4qZ1hm%253Bct%253A201805291855%253Bhn%253A3ddee1' is not allowed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is here: [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2)

You use proxy_handler but don't seem to declare it.

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
```

Comment: Ok, you declare proxy for http, https, and ftp? URL is used for internal URL? edit: Are your URL force the used of cookie?

Comment: I use proxy by luminati.io . its for http, https

Comment: Have you tried to used Luminati Python example like [this one](https://github.com/luminati-io/api/blob/master/python/3.x/simple.py)? Outer url request give the same result ?

Comment: Yes this exactly what we are using. No only some urls with market:// gives this