# Is there a way to make python requests show on fiddler?

Tags: python, fiddler

Is there a way to be able to get python traffic to be able to be read from fiddler, as at the moment it does not record what python is doing? Could the problem just be resolved by using a different OS and if so which OS would be suitable for this problem not to occur?

Have already tried using http debugger proxy fire, but since python doesn't use windows certificate nothing is being recorded.

Answer (score 0):

It will only work if you set [Python to use Fiddler as a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2). It may be easier to use Wireshark, which will let you monitor all HTTP traffic, without the need for proxies.

Comment: In Wireshark it doesn't let me see headers, because that its encrypted in SSL and heard that a key is needed to decrypt it.

Comment: yes, a key is needed in order to decrypt them, and if your having this problem with wireshark your gonna have it also with fiddler even if you configure python to use it.

Comment: @BlakeCook Yes configure requests to use the Fiddler proxy - there is an example of doing that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431689/migrating-from-python-2-7-urllib2-to-python-3-7-requests-on-windows-fiddler In Fiddler go to Options->https and enable decryption. You don’t need any extra certificate, Fiddler will generate one, but it will make your browser ask you to accept the Fiddler cert because it isn’t a real cert - it can’t be so don’t get wrapped up in thinking you need a ‘real’ cert. Any proxy will have the same issue when you are using https. On Linux use `mitm`