# Python 2.7 (urllib2). How use SSL HTTPS Proxy?

Tags: python, ssl, https, proxy, urllib2

How use Secure Web Proxy, like documented [this](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/secure-web-proxy) (443, HTTPS) with urllib2?
For example, i'm trying

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler, urllib2.HTTPSHandler,urllib2.ProxyHandler({"https": 'https://some_proxy.com:443'}))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

but getting timeout. 
The proxy is works in others applications, such on browsers via PAC file.

P.S. [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2) not duplicate question, because doesn't have info about Secure Web Proxy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager

http = ProxyManager("https://some.proxy.com:8080/")
response = http.request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

if you want to send headers as well to the proxy then

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers

default_headers = make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='username:password')
http = ProxyManager("https://some.proxy.com:8080/", headers=default_headers)
response = http.request('GET', 'https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: you can try. I don't have any proxy to verify.

Comment: How did u handled the ssl verification exception?

Comment: Try this... Second answer..
Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569042/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-python3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193244/discussion-between-tech-at-the-sparks-foundation-and-ilw).